# sql update with aggregate functions in where clause

Tags: sql-server

i have a table like this 
with these fields >>>

i want where number of s-id=1 >>>>relevancy value updated to 2

```
(s-id)(relevancy)
0         null
0         null
3         2
4         null
4         null
4         null
4         null
5         2
9         null
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    SELECT s-id,COUNT(s-id) from ccc
    group by s-id

    update ccc set Relevancy=2 where COUNT(s-id)=1
```

but i figured that aggregate function can't be used in where clause,what should i do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE ccc SET Relevancy = 2 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ccc c2 WHERE c2.[s-id] = ccc.[s-id])  = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b74c5/2/1)</kbd> (last row's `Relevancy` is updated to 2 since 9 is unique)

Another option is using a `CTE` with `COUNT(*)OVER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [s-id], Relevancy,
           CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [s-id])
    FROM CCC
)
UPDATE CTE SET Relevancy = 2 WHERE CNT = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5dd4/2/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
update   dbo.YourTable
set      Relevancy = 2
where    [s-id] in
         (
         select  [s-id]
         from    dbo.YourTable
         where   Relevancy <> 2
         group by
                 [s-id]
         having  count(*) = 1
         )
```